# Why android project downloads old 30.0.3 version of build tools?

Tags: android, gradle

I always try to use latest but lately something changed and my project seems to be downloading old or maybe gradle default version of Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3. I have specified in all my project gradle files buildToolsVersion "34.0.0" still it seems to ignore that.

I believe before I was juste removing buildToolsVersion because it used latest installed version but this seems to have changed.

Is there some solution ?
Is this some new AGP bug?
Should I ignore that and just keep libing with old version and remove 34 completly?

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
...
    defaultConfig {
        buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
    ...
```

I was trying to force it like this everywhere, yeah I know it does not have to be on two places,but I just wanted to be sure.